# Make an animation when height auto change

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, animation, sass

I am trying to make my div have animation when it have different height and when I click to Agreement it will have different height.

How can I achieve the animation slide up and slide down depends on height of the div?

I made a sample code on codesandbox for a better look: https://codesandbox.io/s/lucid-tree-6lk3v?file=/src/App.js

Comment: What animation? I mean what kind ? What are you gonna animated ?

Comment: It's difficult to answer this question without more details, but you may want to look into [CSS transitions](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_transitions.asp).

Comment: Like it slide up and slide down when height change

Comment: Use CSS property `transition `  it will make it animated. Example `transition :0.5s `.

Comment: Do i need to do some transition-property: height or something?

Comment: Anyone know how I can achieve the animation?

Comment: You are not changing the height , You are changing contents of the div#team-management-tab-panes , Apart from that height between auto and numbers can't be animated . 

You would need to use max-height for that

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3508605/how-can-i-transition-height-0-to-height-auto-using-css?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: One way to do this is to calculate full height by summing up the height of elements in the list and then transition from 0 to that height but its not the best solution

Comment: So what is the best solution in this case?

Comment: Anyone know the best way to implement this?